# Create pop up message in django

Tags: python, django

I am doing some calculations in my `views.py` and I want to show the result.

I have tried to use the following:

```
return render(request, index.html{message:variable})
```

and

```
return HttpResponse(message)
```

I want to show the result as a Popup message. How can I implement this?

Comment: popup? you suppose do it in front end using html based on response what django sents

Comment: You'll need to call your view via JavaScript, get your response and show the response in some modal via JavaScript. That's how popups work. Unless you want to reload the whole page and show the popup only on "startup".

Answer (score 1):

first you have to render template by

```
return render_template( "example.html",message = any_variable)
```

and then you can show pop up on html via java script by

```
<script>

    alert("This is alert box!");  // display string message

    alert( {{message}} ); // display python variable

</script>
```

although i recommend using jinja as template

Comment: Why should recommend using Jinja in place of Django templating?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Jinja2 is a templating library that can be used to simplify the process of generating HTML for Python web apps. Django, on the other hand, is a full-fledged MVC framework. So, the functionality provided by Jinja2 is simply a piece of the functionality that's provided to you by Django. Django also includes its own templating library, which works a bit differently than Jinja2. So, the functionality provided by Jinja2 is simply a piece of the functionality that's provided to you by Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django messages https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'Success')
```

In your template, use something like:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```